# Why does my launch image have a stretched icon image behind it, and how do get rid of it?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app that I am updating for iOS 7, and am using Asset Catalogs for storing icons and launch images. I have included the properly sized launch images, and deleted all previous icon and launch image files.

Now, when I launch the app I get a stretched out "missing icon" graphic behind my launch image that looks like this:

[image]

I have the latest version of Xcode (5.0.2), I have restarted mac/Xcode, and cleaned the project. I have also tried ditching asset catalogs and just went with the naming conventions (default & default-568h@2x) with the same above results.

When I import the app icon image, then *that* image is stretched out behind the launch image. I'm gathering the general reason this is happening is that iOS will display a stretched out icon when the launch images is not in the bundle, but obviously the launch image *is* in the bundle.

How do I only show my launch image when my app is launched?

Note: the subtle "polka dots" in the background is part of the launch image.

Comment: Does it work on a physical device? Have you tried to delete the app from the simulator?

Comment: I wonder if xCode is getting confused by transparency in the icon background ?

Comment: Please show us the LaunchImage property from your Images.xcassets

Comment: @Mikael - Yes and yes. Same result.

Comment: @Ohnomycoco - Yes!! That was it, the image had transparency in it. I just added a white background behind the transparent texture, and all is well now. Write up an answer and I will accept it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest checking the transparency of the icon background - I think xCode is reading it incorrectly.